# how to implement the oauth2 serverconfiguration in spring boot 2.0 M7?

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0

how to implement the oauth2 server using jwt to get clients from database in spring boot 2.0 M7 ? there is any example, I just found an example with spring boot 2.0. M4 but seems it is not compatible with M7 , could someone please  provide me a example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Support for the spring-security-oauth2 dependency was removed from Spring Boot 2.0 in favor of Spring Security 5’s first class OAuth support. Functionality from the [Spring Security OAuth project](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/) is still being migrated to core Spring Security. For Authorization server and Resource server support which has not been migrated yet, you will need to add a dependency on an additional jar. See this [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/) for more details.